# $(F\ast G)(x)\leq F(x)G(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, convolution

Consider the CDFs $F$ and $G$ on $\mathbb R_+$.

How can I show that $$(F\ast G)(x)\leq F(x)G(x),\ \ \ x \in \mathbb R_+$$

$|(F\ast G)(x)|\leq\int_{\mathbb R_+}|F(x-y)G(y) |dy$ but how do I continue? Do we have that $F$ is bounded? (because it is a cdf, so it is bounded by $1$?) Then I could write $...\leq \|F\|_\infty\|G\|_1=\|G\|_1$

?

How would a 'probabilistic' (I don't know if this is the correct word) look like? (i.e. using appropriate random variables and probabilities?

**Edit:**

Apparently, for distribution functions, the convolution is defined as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x-y)dG(y)$$ which is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x-y)G'(y)dy$$ for absolute continuous $G$.

Instead of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x-y)G(y)dy$$

Okay, so this should be the solution:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x-y)dG(y)=\int_{0}^{x}F(x-y)dG(y)\leq\int_{0}^{x}F(x)dG(y)=F(x)G(x),\quad x \geq 0$

Comment: The statement in the question is not true, as the counter-example in my answer shows. However, we can get a weaker estimate, which has been proved in my answer.

Comment: Another counter-example:  let $F(x)=1$ for all $x\ge 1$, $0$ otherwise. The inequality to be proved, for $x\ge 1$, becomes $\int_1^x G(y)\,dy\le G(x)$. But the LHS diverges to $\infty$, while the RHS is bounded. Perhaps $F*G$ does not refer to the convolution of $F$ and $G$ themselves, but rather the random variables they represent. That is, if $X$ has cdf $F$, and $Y$ has cdf $G$, and $X$ is independent of $Y$, then $F*G$ may refer to the cdf of $X+Y$. In this case, the result would be true, as $P(X+Y\le x)\le P(X\le x)P(Y\le x)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for your help! Apparently my definition for the convolution was wrong. I edited it above. Now the statement should be correct but I still don't know how to show it

Answer (score 1):

Before dealing with the problem itself, we may need one more setting.

Because we have talked about convolution, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb R^+}F(x-y)G(y)dy$, we need that $F$ is also define on $\mathbb R^-$. The reason is that, for any fixed $x\in\mathbb R^+$, when $y$ ranges over $\mathbb R^+$, $x-y$ will range over $(-\infty, x)$. Since your functions $F$ and $G$ are CDFs, we may assume that they are zero on $\mathbb R^-$(i.e. we identify the zero extensions of them with themselves).

With this setting in mind, we can get started now.

**The statement in the question is not true, at least for large x.**

**Counter-Example:**

First, because $F$ and $G$ are CDFs, we know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)=1=\lim_{x\to\infty} G(x)$. And since CDFs are non-decreasing, there exists a real number $a$ s.t. $F(a)>0.9$ and $G(a)>0.9$ .

Pick an $x\in\mathbb R^+$ so large that $x-(a+100)>a.$ So,  $\forall y\in(a,a+100),$ $x-y>a.$

Then, $$\int_a^{a+100} F(x-y)G(y)dy>\int_a^{a+100} F(a)G(a)dy=F(a)G(a)\cdot 100 >81.$$

Because $F$ and $G$ are non-negative, we have that, $$\int_{\mathbb R^+}F(x-y)G(y)dy >\int_a^{a+100} F(x-y)G(y)dy>\int_a^{a+100} F(a)G(a)dy=F(a)G(a)\cdot 100>81.$$

But $F(x)\le 1$ and $G(x)\le 1,$ which implies that for this $x$, we have that $(F\ast G)(x) >81>1 \ge F(x)G(x),$ i.e. $(F\ast G)(x) > F(x)G(x).$

---

**A weaker result (maybe also the best result) we can prove will be:** $(F\ast G)(x)\le xG(x)F(x) ,\,\forall x\in \mathbb R^+.$

Fix $x \in \mathbb R^+.$

$|(F\ast G)(x)|\leq\int_{\mathbb R^+}|F(x-y)G(y) |dy=\int_{A\cup B}|F(x-y)G(y) |dy,$ where $A:= \mathbb{R^+} \cap \{x\geq y\}$ and $B:= \mathbb{R^+} \cap \{x\lt y\}$.

On $B$, $F=0,$ and so the integral over $B$ is zero.

On A, because $\{ x\ge y\}$, we see $G(y)\le G(x), \forall y \in A.$ This is the non-decreasing property of CDF.

So, $\int_A|F(x-y)G(y) |dy\le G(x)\int_A|F(x-y) |dy\le G(x)\int_A|F(x)|dy$, where the last inequality holds because CDF is non-negative and non-decreasing and $x-y\in [0,x)$ on $A$.

Now, $G(x)\int_A|F(x)|dy\le G(x)|F(x)|\int_A dy= G(x)|F(x)|x=G(x)F(x)x$.

So we have shown that, $(F\ast G)(x)\le xG(x)F(x).\,\forall x\in \mathbb R^+.$

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**Remark 1:** By the estimate we proved in the answer, we can see that the statement in the problem is true for $x\in(0,1].$ But as the counter-example shows, it is not true for large $x$.

**Remark 2:** Actually we don't need any absolute sign in the proof, because every CDF and the convolution of CDFs are non-negative. I didn't realize this when I started writing the proof. I am lazy to change it but you should be aware of this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Apparently my definition for the convolution was wrong. I edited it above. Now the statement should be correct but I still don't know how to prove it

Comment: @obvth213 Glad that you have found the answer as in your edit.